# Package 'octave-octcdf' has no installation candidate (Ubuntu 18 LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, repository, octave

I need to install `octave-octcdf` package to work with Octave in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I tried, `sudo apt-get install -y octave-octcdf`. But this receives an error as following;

```
user@PowerEdge-R540:~/user/tools$ sudo apt-get install -y octave-octcdf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package octave-octcdf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'octave-octcdf' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help to properly install `octave-octcdf` package?

Answer (score 3):

`octave-octcdf` is no longer available, [`octave-netcdf` replaces it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=819527): use

```
sudo apt install octave-netcdf
```

instead.